# Scrapy | Follow links that are loaded by a dynamic "Load More"-Button

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I know this question was asked a few times with similar approaches, but I can't wrap my head around it. That is why I want to open a specific case/question.

**The situation**

I crawl a website which displays articles, let's say 20 (but the website has 200). I follow the article links and there I will extract the data I need. So far, so good.

Some pages appear to have a **Load More** button instead of "normal" pagination to show more than the 20 articles. And here is where the struggle begins. I inspected the page (like described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EelmnSzykyI) with that [example](http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll) for example). However, the structure of the request URL when clicking the button differs from the one described in the video. Because the structure will remain the same instead of loading pages like http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?**page=8**, "**page=9**" etc.

I found websites with following Request URL's when clicking the button:

- https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
- https://example2.com/api/v1/content/json/_mp

In both examples, when clicking the button, the link will not change. So I am kind of lost and can't apply the solution of the tutorials I took.

**What I think the solution could be is using Splash**, like described [here](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash). It states:

> It’s often the case that you need to click a button before the page is displayed. We can do that using splash:mouse_click function:

```
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    local get_dimensions = splash:jsfunc([[
        function () {
            var rect = document.getElementById('button').getClientRects()[0];
            return {"x": rect.left, "y": rect.top}
        }
    ]])
    splash:set_viewport_full()
    splash:wait(0.1)
    local dimensions = get_dimensions()
    splash:mouse_click(dimensions.x, dimensions.y)
    -- Wait split second to allow event to propagate.
    splash:wait(0.1)
    return splash:html() 
end
```

I installed splash and set all the settings. However, I really struggle with how to integrate this in my scrapy code. And will this actually work or is this function just clicking the button once? Furthermore, the button element of the websites I scrape do not have an ID, just a class name (but I guess that is not the problem I struggle with).

**I would really appreciate any input on either how to integrate this splash function into my scrapy code or another solution to follow links loaded by a dynamic load more button.**

Here is a snippet of my Code (without Splash, just following links and scraping items):

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://example.com",
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to article
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="article"]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        def get_with_xpath(query):
             return response.xpath(query).get(default='').strip()


        yield {
            'title': get_with_xpath('//meta[@name="title"]/@content'),
            'description': get_with_xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content')

            }
```

Comment: Some tips: (1) Don't click on X,Y coordinates. Rather find the button using [`splash:select`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-select) and then trigger a click with [`element:mouse_click`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html#element-mouse-click). It should be more robust in case things move around.

Comment: (2) To launch this from Scrapy you have to yield a `SplashRequest`. That comes from [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash). Have a look at the section "Run a simple Splash Lua Script" on that linked page.

Comment: Play around with that first and then come back with specific questions.